# Getting GUID from ConcurrentQueue

Tags: c#-4.0

I am trying get out value of GUID from Queue But I am not getting the right value.
Can I know where I am getting wrong.

```
var gid=Guid.NewGuid();
Guid  value ;
var queue1 = new ConcurrentQueue<Guid>();
queue1.Enqueue(gid);
while(queue1.TryDequeue(out value));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ConcurrentQueue<T>.TryDequeue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287208%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will **always** write to the `Guid`, since it's an `out` parameter.

The second time through the while loop, it clears out the value.

What's happening is, the first time you hit the while statement, the dequeue operation succeeds.  It then tries to dequeue *again*, which fails (since there is only a single element), and sets the output (`value`) to `default(Guid)`.

If you do the following, you'll see the two values are the same:

```
var gid=Guid.NewGuid();
Guid value ;
var queue1 = new ConcurrentQueue<Guid>();
queue1.Enqueue(gid);
if(queue1.TryDequeue(out value))
{
    Console.WriteLine("gid==value: {0}", gid == value);
}
else
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to dequeue");
```